# Desktop PC with RAID won't boot

Tags: windows, boot, raid, sata

I'm trying to fix my dads PC (Windows 10) being on holiday at my parents place. He has a RAID Volume installed, built of 2 SATA discs where at least one disk seems to be corrupt - it makes an ugly scratchy sound (that later disapears after WINDOWS had gone through repair attempts, to eventually reappear later).

- If the scratchy sound can be heard, then that disk won't be listed in BIOS and the RAID status says "DEGRADED"; but also claims Bootable = YES, which is not true and leads to a blue screen if booted. (BAD SYSTEM CONFIG INFO).
- If the scratchy sound is not showing up, then both discs are listed and the RAID status says "Repair" and again Bootable = Yes, with the same outcome and blue screen when booted.

In BIOS Utility advanced mode there is an option to switch the current SATA mode RIAD to deactivated, IDE or AHCI. I am wondering if this would allow to boot regulary from one of the disc, without overwriting anything on that disc which is currently my main concern.

Another idea I came up with is to physically install the disc (the one that doesn't make that scratchy sound) inside my desktop PC and access the disk that way in order to restore it's data, but I don't know if the fact that it was working in a RAID enviornment would have any affect on the accessibility.

Any idea, hint, recommendation or link is highly appreciated!
Thanks, Martin

Comment: What type of RAID? Your hopes of recovery are directly tied to this piece of information.

Comment: I never had worked with RAID and I don't know if to answer this more specific than I already did. If I look up I see: Intel Rapid Storage Technology. Option ROM 12.0.0.1703. RAID Volumes: ... Level RAID1(Mirror)/ Strip N/A... does that help? Otherwise, do I find the more specific information in Bios?

Comment: OK - RAID 1 you have a chance. One drive should simply be a mirror of the other, so either should be capable of being recovered. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels

Comment: You should be able to replace the bad disk, have the RAID recover itself, then replace the other disk.  Whatever you do, the drives are clearly on their last leg, so backing up the data is vital.  **Switching to IDE or AHCI instead of RST will make Windows unbootable.**

Comment: I'm afraid that these consideration about the RAID being bootable if at least one of the mirrored discs is functional are only theoretical. The fact is that the system won't boot and I'm afraid that the damage might have affected both discs. I will connect the disc to my PC and try to restore the data that way